# UISearchBar textDidChange not firing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm new to iOS programming, and I'm not sure why my `textDidChange` function is not firing.  Searched online a bunch, but can't find out what's different between my code and everyone else's.  Here's what my *.h* and *.m* files look like for this view controller:

*CategoryTableViewController.h*:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface CategoryTableViewController : UITableViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnBack;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *txtSearchBar;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *allCategories;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredCategories;

//A stack containing the parent categories used to get to the current category.
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *parentCategories;

@end
```

Relevant code from *CategoryTableViewController.m*:

```
-(void)txtSearchBar:(UISearchBar*)txtSearchBar textDidChange: (NSString*)text
{

    //do something
}
```

I used Xcode's ctrl+click+drag to create the reference to the search bar in the header file.  I put breakpoints and print statements at the start of the `textDidChange` code, but none of it ever gets called.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the delegate property of txtSearchBar to use the delegate methods.
Make sure you add

```
    self.txtSearchBar.delegate = self;
```

in ViewDidLoad()

and the delegate method

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    //Do something

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.  I wasn't setting the delegate of txtSearchBar, and my delegate method was using 'txtSearchBar' instead of 'searchBar'.  Changing it to 'searchBar' fixed my issue.  :)

Comment: ;) I noticed the wrong method name in your code. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a delegate method be sure to set the delegate property on the instance that needs to call the delegate so it knows there is a delegate and where to send actions.

if you're using Interface Builder and not delegate, you need to create an IBAction function, or you can use a UIControl's subclass addTarget() method to create a callback for a given event type.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
self.txtSearchBar.delegate = self
```

in viewDidLoad().

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have this before.  I added this line, but it's still not getting inside the textDidChange function when the search bar changes.  Do I need to do anything else?